# JSON Array Results from Census

Tags: arrays, json, census

I have a url that returns data from the Census. I receive the follow back when I do the call:

```
[["PCT012A015","PCT012A119","state"],
["20604","19526","01"]]
```

Since there are no names, the problem I am having is that I can't figure out how to define the path to get all the values from a particular "column".

Comment: Which language are you using to process the data? Either way, just use the index of the column.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with an array rather than an object, you have indices rather than key names. You can access the items in the array using the index.  For example, in an array defined as follows:

```
var a = { 'a', 'b', 'c' }
```

You can access the second element, 'b' using its index in the array, like so: `a[1]`

Keep in mind that these indices begin at zero (0).  So, to access the first element in this array, you access `a[0]`.  The second element is at `a[1]` and so on.  a.length indicates how many items are in the array, and it will always be numerically greater than the highest index (by one) in the array.

Assuming that each line in your supplied JSON example is a row, and the items within each row are columns, then you can access each item in a given column using a loop.

Let's say we want the second item of each array and we want to store it in a new array, `secondValInEach`.

Take the JSON object and assign it to a variable, then iterate through it.

```
var example = [["PCT012A015","PCT012A119","state"],["20604","19526","01"]]

var secondValInEach = []

example.forEach(function(entry){
  secondValInEach.push(entry[1])
})
```

When the code completes, you should have the following in `secondValInEach`:

```
["PCT012A119", "19526"]
```